# Sqlite max columns number configuration from QT

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, configuration

I want to store rows that have 65536 columns in a Sqlite database, and I am doing that using C++ and QT.

My question is: Since the default maximum number of columns seems to be 2000 no more, how to configure this parameter from C++ and Qt?

Thank you.

Comment: "I want to store rows that have 65536 columns" suggests you need to redesign the database.

Answer (score 2):

The [SQLLite homepage](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) has some explanation on this:

> 2.Maximum Number Of Columns
>
> The SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN compile-time parameter is used to set an upper
>   bound (...)

and

> The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000. You can change it
>   at compile time to values as large as 32767. On the other hand, many
>   experienced database designers will argue that a well-normalized
>   database will never need more than 100 columns in a table.

Like that, even if you increased it, you could only achieve half of what you want. Apart from that I can only refer to Styne666's comment on your post.

Comment: Hello.

Thank you very much for your answer. I see, I will redesign the database.